# Is it ok to optimize w.r.t. a monotonically increasing function of $x$ instead of $x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization

Given the multivariate constrained optimization problem

$$
\max_{\mathbf{w}} f(y(\mathbf{w})) \:\:\:\: s.t. \:\:\: g(y(\mathbf{w})) = \overline{g}
$$

Where $\mathbf{w}$ is a vector of control variables, $\overline{g}$ is a constant, and $\mathbf{y}$ is a vector of uncoupled functions of the elements $w_i$ in $\mathbf{w}$. More specifically, $y_i = k_i (w_i / C)^{\alpha_i}$, where $0 < \alpha_i < 1$ and $k_i > 0$ are parameters that are different for each $i$, and $C > 0$ is a global parameter.

Can I just reformulate the problem as

$$
\max_{\mathbf{y}} f(\mathbf{y}) \:\:\:\: s.t. \:\:\: g(\mathbf{y}) = \overline{g}
$$

And then take the optimal solution $\mathbf{y}^*$ and deduce the optimal $\mathbf{w}^*$ as

$$
w_i^* = C (y_i^* / k_i)^{1 / \alpha_i}
$$

Comment: If $R = y(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the range of $y$ then the problem is equivalent to $\max\{ f(x) | g(x) = \overline{g}, x \in R \}$. You need the restriction $x \in R$.

Comment: @copper.hat I'll take that as a yes.

Comment: A qualified yes.